# Getting single value from a single row with Mysql/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Often I just need to get a single value from MySQL that I know exists there. I use the following construct:

```
$result = end(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()', $db)));
```

Is there a proper single function in PHP that would do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [mysql_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) will do this.

```
$result = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()', $db), 0);
```

Comment: didn't notice the optional params of mysql_result. I guess that this is the limit - there is no function that combines mysql_query and mysql_result?

Comment: If you make a lot of these calls you should create your own function that combines the two. As far as I know, no such function exists natively.