# select found rows mysql php code

Tags: php, mysql

I just found this on stack [Getting single value from a single row with Mysql/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962479/getting-single-value-from-a-single-row-with-mysql-php):

```
$result = end(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()', $db)));
```

I searched and could not find an easy to understand description on google.

Could somebody please explain select found_rows()?

What would $db possibly look like?

Does this return a particular value of a row or the entire row like select *?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$db` is a MySQL connection handle. `FOUND_ROWS()` returns the total number of rows that would have been returned if the query didn't have a `LIMIT` clause, without re-running the query.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what a mysql connection handle is, do you mean a mysql_query command?  IF not, is their an example possible?

Comment: No, it's basically an object that represents the *connection* to the MySQL server (created with `mysql_connect`), and it's passed to the `mysql_query` call so it knows what connection to make the query through.

Comment: You mentioned : "if the query didn't have a LIMIT clause" Which query did you mean?