# Creating a Pagination class in PHP

Tags: php, oop, pagination

I want to build a `paginator` class, but i'm not sure what the best method is. I see many different codes on the internet that confuses me.

My data is stored in a MySQL database. Do i have to give a query to my pagniator class so that it can retrieve the data out of MySQL for me (and of course it will automatically do some pagination calculations after that)? Or do i get all the data from a `model` first, then supply the returned `array` from that model to the `paginator` class?

In either way i'd probably have to do another query to get the "total" amount of records and pass that result to the `pagninator` class as a separate param.

Once i know how to get started then i know how to pick up the rest. I'm just not sure how to pass in the data to the `paginator` class and what kind of data.

Any idea how to build a good `paginator` class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5153815/522479 could be relevant.

Comment: [this blog post might be useful](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-unless-you-plan-on-learning-more-about-wheels.html), along with [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.paginator.usage.html), and on the link posted by @Cobra_Fast: know that `mysql_*` is being deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore

Comment: `do i get all the data from a model first` no you should only pull out the rows that you need to display, don't grab the entire table on each page view....

Comment: @Vivendi - Do you have any questions or feedback on my answer?  I took quite a bit of time putting it together for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A well designed OO `Paginator` class should be independent of your data and your database.

It should take parameters like `count`, `page`, and `per_page`, and should return objects that can be used for Dependency Injection into a Model for generating queries with the appropriate `LIMIT`, or into a `PaginationHelper` class for rendering the appropriate HTML.

Example of what might be a good Paginator interface (given 10 minutes of thought in this):

```
/**
 * Your pagination master class
 */
interface iPaginator {
    public function __construct($total_count, $count_per_page, $current_page=1);
    public function getPaginationLimiter();
    public function getPaginationHelper();

    // These return iPaginatorPage objects
    public function getCurrentPage();
    public function getNextPage();
    public function getPreviousPage();

    public function getTotalCount();
    public function getCountPerPage();
    public function getPageCount(); // Calculated
}

/**
 * Page representation
 */
interface iPaginatorPage {
    public function __construct($page_number, $start, $end);

    public function getNumber();
    public function getStart();
    public function getEnd();
    public function getCount(); // Calculated
}

/**
 * Helper for rendering the UI
 */
interface iPaginationHelper {
    public function __construct(iPaginator $paginator);
    public function render();
}
```

Example of how you could integrate into your model, by extending your base model, and then having your application models extend PaginatorModel instead of Model:

```
class PaginationModel extends Model {
    public function query($sql, iPaginatorPage $page = null) {
        if (!empty($page)) {
            $start = $page->getStart();
            $length = $page->getCount();
            $sql .= " LIMIT ({$start}, {$length})";
            return parent::query($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Made some tweaks.  I'm relatively happy with this now.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a pretty good idea how to get started. One thing i couldn't figure out from your code though. I don't see how can i let the pagination class know how many records there are in total? Any idea what a good approach would be?

Comment: @Vivendi - the $total_count parameter in the __construct() identifies how many records there are in total.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [pager](http://pear.php.net/package/Pager/redirected) implementation from Pear. It's a very nice class, simple to use and with a lots of cool features.

Answer (score 0):

create class, and have function like this:

1. function resultset($required_filters, $table, $pagenum, $records){
        $getCount='SELECT count(*) from table';
        $sql="SELECT ".$required fields." FROM ".$table." LIMIT ".(($pagenum-1) * $records).",".$records;
        $sqlres=...
        return array($getCount, $sqlres); }

   call this function as  list($rescount, $arrData)=resultset(all
   parameters);

and for pagination use some for loop to display page numbers...for total $rescount pages,
using get you can show current pagenum highlighted