# Using php to access mysql, how can I get the query result which is only a number?

Tags: php, mysql

For example, for some queries like SELECT MAX(field), the query result is usually only a field value, rather than returning rows to you.

Now the field of the value I wanna get is integer type.
As I'm a beginner of php, how can I get that value from the query result?
As I do the following

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(stringid) FROM XMLString";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
echo $result;
```

Then nothing is echoed out.
I have check the db connection made by mysqlconnect, and it's got no problem.
And I tried this query in MySQL at phpMyAdmin, then the query is what I want, too?

So why would it be like that, and any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: yes you can - this kind of SQL returns values not rows - but it can return null as well - so check for null before you check numeric answers

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting single value from a single row with Mysql/PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962479/), [Fetching single row, single column with PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666710/).

Answer (score 2):

You will always retrieve rows back from an SQL query, even if there's only one row with one field. You can directly retrieve a specific field of a specific row using [`mysql_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php):

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(stringid) FROM XMLString";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
echo mysql_result($result, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query is not printing results. Maybe try this:

`echo mysql_result($result);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(stringid) as val FROM XMLString";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
$rows   = mysql_num_rows($result); 
if($rows > 0) {
  $rstAry = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  echo $rstAry['val'];
}
```

Try This

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting any result because `mysql_query` returns a database object.

You will need to process this "database object" using `mysql_fetch_array`. This command 'fetches' an `array` out of a MySQL "database object". The `array` you are fetching is the rows your query produced. In your case, it is just one row.

Here is the code:

1. This step sets your query:

   `$query = "SELECT MAX(stringid) as val FROM XMLString";`
2. This step will run your query, and return the database object:

   `$result_database_object_whatever = mysql_query($query, $link);`
3. This step will process the database object, and give you an array of the queried rows:

   `$result_array = mysql_fetch_array($query, $link);`
4. This step will echo the first row returned by your query:

   `echo $result_array[1];`

Comment: It's called a MySQL *result resource*. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(stringid) FROM XMLString";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $fetch['stringid'];
```

The [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) function retrieves the data in an associative array.

Answer (score -1):

Would it help to give the max a name you could reference? Also ifyou think there's syntax errors you could just add the error to help clarify.

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(stringid) as maxNum FROM XMLString";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die(mysql_error());
echo $result;
```